# Spouse visa category and IHS payment

Tags: uk-visa

I applied from Nigeria for a settlement visa to join my wife in the UK who is a British citizen and my sponsor and meets the financial requirements. All supporting documents have been submitted with the application. While filling the application form online, i choose the visa category 'settlement' and sub type to be 'marriage' . I filled the form online and there was no option of paying the IHS fee. I have submitted the application and awaiting a decision without paying for IHS as the option wasn't presented to me.
I however later realised after submitting the application that the visa sub type 'husband' would have given me an option to pay for the IHS. 
Can this possibly affect the decision being made? Is there any way I can pay for it and send to the home office before a decision is made?

Comment: Related: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/14948/6