# IHS payment problem

Tags: uk-visa

Yesterday I submitted my online application and booked my biometrics appointment. I then paid my IHS fee online via PayPal. They (PayPal) sent me an email of payment confirmation but the black indicator of IHS payment in the online application didn't go green.  I was stuck in that stage until my biometrics appointment was canceled by the IHS, and they want me to pay the fee again.

Has anyone had this problem and what can I do?

Comment: Related: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/14741/6

Comment: It is not my case ... I paid the ihs and they sent me my reference number in first email of payment confirmation but the ihs button still black it didn't turn to green and didn't let me pass to the next stage which is paying my visa fee

Comment: I agree, it's not a duplicate, both questions present different questions, they're just a bit related.

Comment: I have (fairly dramatically) edited your question.  Please check that the edited version says what you meant.  The changes were: change "they, them" to refer to specific organiziations; change "bio" to "biometrics"; split into more, shorter, sentences; generally tidy up.